# How do I recursively reduce an element of one/multiple lists contained in a list with python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I need a piece of code that can reduce an element of one or multiple lists contained in a list. This is a sorted list. The reduction must continue until a certain parameter is greater than zero. I see two possible scenarios and I can not figure out a solution that applies to both. I am having a difficulty formulating a logically sound statement for the problem, will try to provide more details if needed. Thanks!

```
#Scenario 1
parameter = 5
data = [[1.99,1],[1.98,1],[1.97,2],[1.96,6]]
#reduction code
data = [[1.99,0],[1.98,0],[1.97,0],[1.96,5]]

#Scenario 2
parameter = 0.5
data = [[1.99,1],[1.98,1],[1.97,2],[1.96,6]]
#reduction code
data = [[1.99,0.5],[1.98,1],[1.97,2],[1.96,6]]
```

the flow of the program is this...
take 2nd element of 1st list reduce it by 1 parameter becomes 5 - 1, continue, take 2nd elemnt of 2nd list reduce it by 1, parameter becomes 3, continue until parameter is 0 (first scenario)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the second scenario has the [1.99, 0.5] pair show up...., but

```
data_reduced = []
for pair in data:
    if pair[1] < parameter:
        pair[1] = 0
    else :
        pair[1] = parameter
    data_reduced.append(pair)
```

Comment: the amount parameter is spread across multiple lists, it does not set it directly because element is lower than it rather it acts as a bank of how much more reduction needs to take place for consequent lists...

Answer (score 1):

`Scenario-1` and `Scenario-2` both are different cases. I can not find any common logic to built formula for it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario:

```
parameter = 3
data = [[1.99,1],[1.98,1],[1.97,2],[1.96,6]]

# copy of data list
data_reduced = data[:]

for n,l in enumerate(data_reduced):
    if  parameter <= 0:
        break
    else:
        l[1] = l[1] - 1
        parameter -= 1

print data_reduced
```

The data list has only 4 elements and you did not describe what should happen if the list is shorter than the parameter counter like in your example (paramater = 5, but only 4 elements in the list), so I reduced the parameter to 3.

The second scenario is completely different, because only the second element of the first list is reduced (and not by 1).